# lost bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

I had 2 OSs, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. They were working fine, but then I installed Arch Linux and it only shows Arch in grub. I think I may have deleted my bootloader.

Things that I tried, but none worked:

- Using Windows 10 DVD repair tool and cmd
- Rescatux 0.73
- Super Grub Disk (It let me enter Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm still unable to boot into Windows 10.)
- Updating grub

and then it doesn't show the grub. Instead it shows an error that says `No partition active` .

I don't care if I need to delete Ubuntu or Arch, but I can't reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: i used the boot repair tool i work and i can see my arch and ubuntu but no win10 and ubuntu shows black screen i used the text only terminal to update grub but it doesn't show win10

Comment: The question I linked to is in my opinion the best question at Ask Ubuntu for questions about being unable to boot Windows in a multiple boot. As you may have noticed there are multiple answers, and not every answer works for every question. The objective with this question was to be inclusive, so that as many questions as possible would be provided with a solution. I recommend that you solve the Ubuntu boot problem first with Super Grub Disk, and then try to solve the Windows boot problem afterwards.